# wget or curl with two forms on same php page

Tags: php, forms, cookies, curl, wget

I am working with a php page with multiple forms. I enter information into the first form and click submit. Then it takes me to the second form where I check "I agree" and hit submit. Both of these forms are on the same php page however.

I can get both curl and wget to act on the first form but not the second. I tried saving the cookie and loading it but neither seems to work. Here is my code for both:

```
curl -k --cookie-jar cookie.txt -d "login=$user&pass=$pass" https://member.testurl.com/login.php
curl -k --cookie cookie.txt -d "i_agree=1&do_agreement=1&data=$data" https://member.testurl.com/login.php

wget --save-cookies testcookie.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data "login=$user&pass=$pass" https://member.testurl.com/login.php
wget --load-cookies testcookie.txt --post-data "i_agree=1&do_agreement=1&data=$data" https://member.testurl.com/login.php
```

As I said, the cookie from the first form appears to save as there is data in the cookie file but I am unable to get to the second form. The second part of either command seems to try and post to the first form again instead of the second. Is the cookie not loading? Something peculiar with the page?

Comment: based on the text i don't understand the usage of wget or curl

Comment: The commands for curl and wget do the same thing. The first command posts login data to https://member.testurl.com/login.php and saves the cookies for the second command to use. The second command is supposed to load those cookies and post to the second form on https://member.testurl.com/login.php, which is an "I agree" page. However, based on the output I received, the second command instead goes but to the first form on the page. I cannot got either wget or curl to post to the second form on the page.

Comment: ah , you are trying to log in to a remote site?

Comment: yes, it is a remote website. i am trying to automate some common maintenance tasks.

Comment: anyone got any ideas? still stumped on this.